# CSS transition on the mask of an SVG?

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I have an image inside an inline SVG that switches between two masks when it is hovered over.

However, the CSS transition is not working with `transition-property: mask;`

**Is there a different method that can be used that works with a CSS transition?**

I also tried styling `<mask>` but it seems that definition elements cannot be styled (?).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 604px; height: 302px; margin: 20px auto;"> <!-- IE needs width AND height specified to scale the SVG inside correctly. -->
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">

 <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
  .mask_hover a:link,
  .mask_hover a:visited {
   mask: url(#mask_right);
  }
  .mask_hover a:hover,
  .mask_hover a:active {
   transition-property: mask;
   transition-duration: 0.4s;
   transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
   mask: url(#mask_left);
  }
  /* ]]> */
 </style>

 <defs>
  <mask id="mask_left">
   <circle id="circle_l" cx="416" cy="216" r="202" fill="#fff"/>
  </mask>
  
  <mask id="mask_right">
   <circle id="circle_r" cx="809" cy="337" r="202" fill="#fff"/>
  </mask>
  
 </defs>
 
 <g class="mask_hover">
  <a xlink:href="#">
   <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
  </a>
 </g>
</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

<sup>Image credit: [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/photos/ladybugs-ladybirds-bugs-insects-1593406/)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not really the `mask` property that can't be animated, but the `url()` <func>.

To create a transition, you need to have a state 1 that goes to a state 2 with the possibility to create an interpolation between both states.
When you use `url(#1)` and wish to go to `url(#2)`, there is no way to create any interpolation between these two states, because `url(#1.5)` will not be the in-between state.

What can be animated though is the content of your mask.

In SVG2, you can set directly the properties that did change (i.e `cx` and `cy`) from CSS, but this is still only supported by Blink&Safari browsers:

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a:link,
    .mask_hover a:visited {
      mask: url(#mask);
    }
    #mask > circle {
      transition-property: cx, cy;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;    
    }
    .mask_hover a:hover + defs #mask > circle,
    .mask_hover a:active + defs #mask > circle {
      cx: 416;
      cy: 216;
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#">
      <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
    </a>
    <!-- we need to move it here so we can target it with our CSS rules -->
    <defs>
      <mask id="mask">
        <circle id="circle_l" cx="809" cy="337" r="202"   fill="#fff"/>
      </mask>  
    </defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```

For other browsers that don't support this part of SVG2, you should be able to do it with the transform property, but somehow, Firefox doesn't accept it...

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a:link,
    .mask_hover a:visited {
    mask: url(#mask);
    }
    #mask > circle {
    transition-property: transform;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;    
    }
    .mask_hover a:hover + defs #mask > circle,
    .mask_hover a:active + defs #mask > circle {
    transform: translate(-393px, -121px);
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#">
     <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
    </a>
  <!-- we need to move it here so we can target it with our CSS rules -->
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
     <circle id="circle_l" cx="809" cy="337" r="202" fill="#fff"/>
    </mask>  
  </defs>
  </g>
</svg>
```

So you may also want to try with SMIL, but there you won't be able to have the `:active` rule, and Safari is buggy in implementing an hover state...

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a:link,
    .mask_hover a:visited {
      mask: url(#mask);
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <circle id="circle_r" cx="809" cy="337" r="202" fill="#fff">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
          attributeType="XML"
          type="translate"
          to="-393 -121"
          dur="0.4s"
          fill="freeze"
          begin="anchor.mouseover"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
          attributeType="XML"
          type="translate"
          to="0 0"
          dur="0.4s"
          fill="freeze"
          begin="anchor.mouseout"/>
      </circle>
   </mask>
  </defs>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#" id="anchor">
      <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>
```

So a final way might be to implement the whole thing using only `clip-path` from CSS:

```html
<svg id="artwork" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1208 604">
  <style type="text/css">
  /* <![CDATA[ */
    .mask_hover a image {
      transition: clip-path .4s;
    }
    .mask_hover a {
      pointer-events: all;
    }
    .mask_hover a:link image,
     .mask_hover a:visited image{
      clip-path: circle(202px at 809px 337px);
    }
    .mask_hover a:hover image,
     .mask_hover a:active image{
      clip-path: circle(202px at 416px 216px);
    }
  /* ]]> */
  </style>
  <g class="mask_hover">
    <a xlink:href="#">
      <image id="img" width="1208" height="604" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCpGU.jpg"/>
      <!-- so we can hover everywhre -->
      <rect fill="none" width="1208" height="604"/>
    </a>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for this well explained answer! I should have explained more about what I'm aiming for and why. The transition I want to animate is a fade-in/fade-out effect. I have done this by animating the opacity of various instances of an image that are each clipped differently ([this is the result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039369/2454914)). The problem is that it is not performant when dealing with a large number of clipping paths (nearly 50). Do you think it would be possible to animate (with a transition) the fill color of the mask from black (invisible) to white (visible)?

Comment: Yes, <color> is now animatable, so this should theoretically work, but once again, you may fall in a lot of discrepancy with various implementations, and particularly old IE may not work.

Comment: Seeing as `<mask>` is inside of `<defs>` by necessity, do you know of a way to target its fill color? I couldn't work it out.

Comment: The same I did: you move the defs as a sibling of your <a> Then `a:hover + defs > mask > circle { fill: #CCC }`

Comment: Ah, I see now. Brilliant! Didn't know that was possible. I will try with that approach.